# React nested json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Let's say I have a JSON object like:

```
posts = [
    {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Title of Post',
        body: 'article content here',
        comment: [
            {
                comment_id: 1,
                author: 'Andy',
                body: 'Comment Body'
            },
            {
                comment_id: 2,
                author: 'Joe',
                body: 'Comment from Joe'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now my question is, I need to display in a react table component the a list of comments, and their post.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Comment Id  |   Author         |    body              |   Post              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1           |   Andy           |    Comment Body      |   Title of Post     |  
| 2           |   Joe            |    Comment from Joe  |   Title of Post     |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What is the best way to approach this? Do I need to create a new object to "flatten" the object? Or there is a better approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could list all the posts by mapping the data like this in your render function:

```
render(){
    let posts = posts.map(post=>{
        let comments = post.comment.map(comment=>{
            return (
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {comment.comment_id}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {comment.author}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {comment.body}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {post.title}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            )
        });
        return (
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Comment Id</td>
                    <td>Author</td>
                    <td>Body</td>
                    <td>Post</td>
                </tr>
                {comments}
            </table>
        );
    });
    return (
        <div>
            {posts}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: I would strongly encourage the OP and yourself to take a more reusable approach when building his/yours components. The above answer will not prove helpful the next time he needs to build a table.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a generic `Table` component, which would accept columns as children and data that will be interpreted into the table rows, in your case the `comments` array. Its usage would be something like this (general idea):

```
<Table data={ posts }>
   <Column name="Comment Id" property="comment_id"></Column>
   <Column name="Author" property="author"></Column>
   <Column name="Body" property="body"></Column>
   <Column name="Post" customProperty={ () => posts.title }></Column>
</Table>
```

Each column would get its data based on the `property` key that it is given, and look it up in `data` prop of its parent. You could also provide `customProperty` in the `Column` component that would be required such as in your case, where the data needed requires values from outside of the scope passed to `Table` component. (That way you can also pass other React components for various, more complex types such as tooltips, or icons, etc)